# Android Sherlock actionbar compatibility issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using Sherlock actionbar to prevent compatibility issue of action bar but my prolem is does not worked well with android 3.0 or later here is my screen snap..

in android  2.2

[image: back version]

now this is fine and i love it..but when i run it on AVD 4.0 it look like this

[image]

the pop-up list shown is displayed when i press menu button.

so how to do the same behavior on higher version also?

Here is my oncreateOptionmenu method..(from which menu inflated)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Is it some kind of standard function for ABS or is it something you've implemented yourself? Some code would be nice. Have you tried cleaning and rebuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the configuration of your Emulator. An Emulator with Android 4.0 should not have a Hardware Back Button instead it should have three software buttons (back, home, used apps)on the screen, my guess is that if a device features a menu button the action bar will get rid of the overflow icon and show the overflow menu if the hardware button is pressed.

Try to configure an Emulator without hardware buttons. For that create a new Emulator and click new in the hardware field. Now choose Hardware Back/Home keys and select no as value.

If you don't get the correct behaviour on this emulator post screenshots from that emulator to give us a further clue.

Comment: Yes this is correct. Confirmed from my galaxy S3. The overflow is "hidden". When i click menu button it pops up the overflow dialog from bottom.

Comment: The galaxy SIII should not have a menu button. Where is the button that you need to click to open the overflow on your phone?

Comment: @Warpzit and Janusz: thanks a lot for stay connected with my problem...so is there any possibility that i can achieve to pops up from top as  in lower version??will just back soon to accept the answer

Comment: @Janusz The galaxy S3 has a hardware menu button. The button is to the left of the home button. To the right of the home button there is a back button. They are not clearly visible as they are touch with white logos on white plastic (my phone). Also the light can turn on and off etc. But trust me its there :D

Comment: @Warpzit Uhh that is a terrible design choice from Samsung.

Comment: @Janusz Ye I completly agree. All they way back to january google wrote on their blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html. But I guess Samgsung decided their android users wasn't all ready for that. So you never know when there is more buttons or not... you have to click it (like in the olden days) and maybe there is more buttons...

Comment: @KpLakhani I think your app is correct but only your emulator is not configured correct so it is shown in an odd way. I edited my answer.

Comment: @KpLakhani You don't have to worry about it. This is device dependent as we are talking about. So on phones with a physical menu button it will pop up from bottom and on phones without it will come from top. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @Warpzit same result on SONY EXPERIA (4.0.x)...So Ultimately my client should not forced me to do the same..:):):)

Comment: @KpLakhani exactly what Warpzit said, you shouldn't implement this yourself, it varies not only by device but also by rom (for android 4.x), for phones running 2.3.3 and below its safe to assume that they will have a menu button and won't require the actionbar menu button

Comment: And Really feel great to see to Two Legends (as per reputed on SO) are discussing on my question...fully satisfied..:):)thanks nd #Respect